# Filling out a dataframe column using parallel processing in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, function, multiprocessing, pool

Trying to compute a value for each row of dataframe in parallel using the following code, but getting errors either when I pass individual input ranges or the combination:

```
#!pip install pyblaze
import itertools
import pyblaze
import pyblaze.multiprocessing as xmp
import pandas as pd

inputs = [range(2),range(2),range(3)]
inputs_list = list(itertools.product(*inputs))
Index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(inputs_list,names={"a", "b", "c"})
df = pd.DataFrame(index = Index)
df['Output'] = 0

print(df)
def Addition(A,B,C):
    df.loc[A,B,C]['Output']=A+B+C
    return df

def parallel(inputs_list):
    tokenizer = xmp.Vectorizer(Addition, num_workers=8)
    return tokenizer.process(inputs_list)
    
parallel(inputs_list)
```